# java set holds element equals to a search key, but return false for 'contains' method

Tags: java, set

How can it be that a set holds the key as a first element

but `contains` method returns `false`?

Does it means the element was different when inserted into the set?

```
public class RuleConditionBl {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        RuleConditionBl that = (RuleConditionBl) o;

        if (weight != that.weight) return false;
        if (isAll != that.isAll) return false;
        if (countries != null ? !countries.equals(that.countries) : that.countries != null) return false;
        if (userFlag != that.userFlag) return false;
        return datesRange != null ? datesRange.equals(that.datesRange) : that.datesRange == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
//        int result = weight;
        int result = 0;
        result = 31 * result + (isAll ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (countries != null ? countries.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (userFlag != null ? userFlag.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (datesRange != null ? datesRange.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably modifying the state of the object after it has been added to the set, thus modifying the hshCode ths breaking the set functionality.

Comment: show some code where you are calling contains method

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the definitions of `countries` and `datesRange`.  If one of those has an incorrect `hashCode` you could get that result.  Also, is it possible that one of the objects is a subclass of `RuleConditionBl`?  If so, we'd have to look at the definitions for `equals()` and `hashCode()` very carefully for the subclasses.

Comment: This is really odd. What collection type exatly is `ruleConditionBls`?

Comment: One more possibility is that your toString function of ruleCondition modifies something in the data. So that after it is being evaluated for your watch rule, the object is now changed. Easiest way to solve this, is to ad a breakpoint in the equals function and just take a look at why it is not equal.