# iterator remove still leaves the element in the set

Tags: java, iterator, set

I have this code:

```
            for (Iterator<RuleConditionBl> iterator = ruleConditionBls.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                RuleConditionBl ruleConditionBl =  iterator.next();
                if (ruleConditionBl.equals(ruleCondition)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
            if (ruleConditionBls.size() == 0)
            {
                countryToNonSplittedRules.remove(country);
            }
```

I see `ruleConditionBls.size == 1` before and after this line is executed `iterator.remove();`

how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you post a complete executable example that demonstrates this (ie a complete class with a main method?)

Comment: is it entering into the if block?

Comment: Most probably the same reason as for your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300874/java-set-holds-element-equals-to-a-search-key-but-return-false-for-contains-m. You're modifying the element after it's been added to the set. Please don't ask more questions related to the same problem. Instead, provide a complete minimal example reproducing it.

Comment: @JBNizet but the `iterator.remove();` is executed on runtime, so it bypass tje origianl calculated `"hashkey"`

Comment: @StinePike is calls ` iterator.remove();`

Comment: @EladBenda2 no. It uses the current hashCode to find the bucket where the element is located, and since the hashCode has changed, it doesn't find it. Just see by yourself: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/a98fbbcfe68ae27952043c01624e8eee

Comment: is there any other thread accessing this?

Answer (score 0):

following `JB Nizet` answer, i have changed my code and it now works:

`It uses the current hashCode to find the bucket where the element is located, and since the hashCode has changed, it doesn't find it.`

```
   Set<RuleConditionBl> ruleConditionBls = countryToNonSplittedRules.get(country);
            if (ruleConditionBls != null) {

                final Set<RuleConditionBl> collect = ruleConditionBls.stream().filter(condition -> !condition.equals(ruleCondition)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                if (collect.size() == 0)
                {
                    countryToNonSplittedRules.remove(country);
                }
                else
                {
                    countryToNonSplittedRules.put(country, collect);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing here. It seems you're trying to circumvent the bug rather than fixing it. Just don't modify objects after they've been stored in a HashSet. You'll have bugs everywhere if you do that.